Determining average compute and memory utilization, per user, on RDS server farm
trying to determine how I might go about doing this.
We have 6 RDS server vms hosted in an esxi environment. I've gathered average utilization for each server vm and each esxi host (in vSphere performance monitoring), but I need to determine how much compute and memory resources are currently being utilized per user on each RDS server.
Anybody have any ideas as to how somebody might be able to approach calculating this?
Thanks

Why? What are you planning to do with the data? Do you need more precise data than averages you can easily calculate based on the current data and user count?

Was an annoying datapoint that a client was very picky/particular about. The reason was that I was building out a new RDS server farm hosted in the US for users working in India. Each of these users use a different set of applications/remote apps. So in order to properly provision resources and determine how best to deploy the remote apps/assign user pools, knowing how much resources a specific user had used over the past x amount of time would have been helpful.

Microsoft provides guidelines for RDS Sizing based on the workload, here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/virtual-machine-recs
The give example of VM in Azure but you can use the guidelines even if your VM are running on-prem.
